# Find Xpath expresion in odoo 8

Tags: xpath, odoo-8, odoo, point-of-sale, pos

I want to find a XPath expression in odoo 8 because i want to replace a word in english into french.

I tried this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<template id="bonus_french_inherit" inherit_id="point_of_sale.index" name="bonusfrench assets">
<xpath expr="/div[not(@id) and not(@class)]/div[text()='Customer name']" position="attributes">
<attribute name="string">Nom du client</attribute>
</xpath>
</template>
</data>
</openerp>
```

In the ticket of point of sale I have this : [ticket point of sale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjerY.png)

When I inspect the element of the ticket in point of sale I have this :

```
 <div class="pos-sale-ticket">

 <div class="pos-center-align">.....</div>

 <div class="pos-center-align" id="ticket-barcode">.....</div>

 <div id="company_logo"><img style="padding-top: 4px; height: 50px; max-width: 100%;" src="...."></div>

 <br>

 Téléphone : <br>

 <br>

 <div>Customer name:.........<br></div>


 <div>Customer bonus points: 380<br><br></div>
```

So, my question is : How to find the Xpath expression for the Customer name and Customer bonus points, they don't have ID or class. How to find their expression Xpath ?

Note : Customer name and Customer bonus points appertain to a module named "pos_loyality", and in the view xml, they are declarend like that :

```
<t t-extend="PosTicket">
<t t-jquery=".pos-sale-ticket table:first" t-operation="before">
<t t-if="customer_name">
<div>Customer name: <t t-esc="customer_name"/><br /></div>
</t>
<t t-if="customer_loyalty_points > -1">
<div>Customer bonus points: <t t-esc="customer_loyalty_points"/><br /><br /></div>
</t>
</t>
</t>
```

Thank's a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To translate from English into any other language, use the i18n tools integrated in Odoo. All text nodes in QWeb templates are exported into ".po" files, which you have to place in your /i18n directory, e.g. fr.po for French. From there, they are automatically imported on module installation/update.

Find relevant documentation here: https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/translations.html

Remove the "xpath" directive from your inherited template.
Then follow the instructions in the documentation to export, creating your own fr.po file. Place this in your modules's "i18n" directory.
Then re-install/update your module.

Edit: I couldn't find a module pos_loyalty in the standard Odoo 8.0 repo. If this is a non-standard module, it may just be missing a French translation.
You can check the original point_of_sale module's fr.po for reference here:
https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/point_of_sale/i18n/fr.po

Comment: Hi, yes I tried first to do the traduction, but the changes did not work...the module is : https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/dusal_pos_bonus/   and the folder i18n doen't exist. And when I export the traduction of this module in french, i have the file .po with the original in english and the traduciton in english. I triend to change the traduction in french, but but the terms remained in English

Comment: ok, that sounds like the right approach though. Next task would be to find out why your translated terms did not show up.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below expressions:

- For Customer name

  ```
  substring-after(//div[starts-with(., "Customer name:")], "Customer name:")
  ```
- For Bonus

  ```
  substring-after(//div[starts-with(., "Customer bonus points:")], "Customer bonus points:")
  ```

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work...I have this error : XMLSyntaxError: Specification mandate value for attribute substring-after, line 5, column 34                                                                                                      <xpath substring-after(//div[starts-with(., "Customer name:")], "Nom du client:")>